# 404 Error during React password reset flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a React password reset flow in my Mern stack app in which on the forgot password screen you enter your email and the server sends a link to your email. Now this functionality is working fine. I do receive the link in my Etherrial SMTP server like this:

```
http://localhost:5173/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NTIyY2U3M2M1NjRlMzcyOWQ2OGJmZmMiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTcyNzE5NTIsImV4cCI6MTY5NzI3Mjg1Mn0.ExaI2p0SdjRI-weyQKAuR4VS2J1KtMQ4YHY8lVe5ezw
```

but when i click on the link or try to go to the link it shows this:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
no webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5173/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NTIyY2U3M2M1NjRlMzcyOWQ2OGJmZmMiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTcyNzE5NTIsImV4cCI6MTY5NzI3Mjg1Mn0.ExaI2p0SdjRI-weyQKAuR4VS2J1KtMQ4YHY8lVe5ezw
HTTP ERROR 404
```

But I have set up everything correctly here is the route that i have set up

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <PublicLayout />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: 'courses',
        element: <Courses />,
      },
      {
        path: 'single-course',
        element: <Course />,
      },
      {
        path: 'testing',
        element: <Testing />,
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        element: <Contact />,
      },
      {
        path: 'about-us',
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: 'faq',
        element: <FAQ />,
      },
      {
        path: 'events',
        element: <Events />,
      },
      {
        path: 'event-details',
        element: <EventDetails />,
      },
      {
        path: 'library',
        element: <Library />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    loader: dashboardLoader(queryClient),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ProfilePage />,
        action: profileAction(queryClient),
      },
      {
        path: 'candidate',
        element: <div>this is candidate</div>,
      },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        element: <Admin />,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'users',
            element: <Users />,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'support',
        element: <div>this is support</div>,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    element: <Login />,
    action: loginAction(queryClient),
    loader: loginLoader,
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    element: <Register />,
    action: registerAction,
    loader: registerLoader,
  },
  {
    path: '/forgotPassword',
    element: <ForgotPassword />,
    action: forgotPasswordAction,
  },
  {
    path: '/reset-password/:token',
    element: <ResetPassword />,
    action: ResetPasswordAction,
  },
])
```

and I know that the route and component works because if i put `http://localhost:5173/reset-password/123` the page does show up and show me the reset password component.

Comment: That route and URL path works for me in a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/404-error-during-react-password-reset-flow-4lw9fl). I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe, so perhaps the issue is elsewhere. Are you running your React app on `"http://localhost:5173"`? Normally it runs on port 3000. Any other information you can provide? See [mcve].

Comment: yes, I am running it on http://localhost:5173. The path and route work for me also if I go to http://localhost:5173/reset-password/123 it does show the reset password page. It is just that if I have the proper token instead of 123 it shows 404.
Like this doesn't work 
http://localhost:5173/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NTIyY2U3M2M1NjRlMzcyOWQ2OGJmZmMiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTcyNzE5NTIsImV4cCI6MTY5NzI3Mjg1Mn0.ExaI2p0SdjRI-weyQKAuR4VS2J1KtMQ4YHY8lVe5ezw.
What other information do you need? I can provide that also please tell me.

Comment: Anything that helps anyone here reproduce the issue would help.

Comment: Try passing the token in the search string instead.

Comment: What do you mean by search string can you give me an example?

Comment: Take a look at this link with half part of the token. This renders the reset password page but when the token is full length it shows 404 I don't understand what Is happening.
http://localhost:5173/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9

Comment: I would guess that the dots in the token cause the problem.

Comment: Pass the token in the URL search string instead as part of the URL path. That target path is working for me, but perhaps the server you are using struggles with URL paths with `"."` characters. Moving the token to the search patterns should help fix that.

Comment: Yup, that's what I noticed the "." is causing the issue but I have worked with the "." in the token before and never faced the issue.  @DrewReese. Yup, thats a possible solution I am going to go with the URL search sting approach for now.

Comment: If you need further help with this new direction feel free to [edit] your post to include the new and relevant details and [mcve] for what you've tried.